# Show loading before load data to webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

how can I show a loading image when this code running ?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
      try
      {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line;
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              str.append(line);
      }
          objwebview.loadData(str.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
      objwebview.loadData(e.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
  }
```

Comment: use ProgressDialog for loading dialog, Before you hit the server, start the dialog and after getting response, attach it to the main thread and dismiss the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code as for showing loading bar using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class Getdataasynktask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {     
      // show loaging bar here

    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0); // set percentage completed to 0%
    progressDialog.show();
          
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          String strdata= getdatafromserver();
            return strdata;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute(String result) {
        
       objwebview.loadData(result.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
       // dismiss progress bar here
       progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
 public String getdatafromserver(){
     String line;
      objwebview.loadData(str.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
      try
      {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
         
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              str.append(line);
      }
          
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
      line=e.toString();
     
  }
return line;
}
}
```

for executing this AsyncTask from UI Thread use

```
new Getdataasynktask().execute("");
```

and you can also use `onProgressUpdate` and `publishProgress` for showing loading bar using `AsyncTask` and publishing results to Ui thread . for more info see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: It seems onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() are mixed up (i.e, progressDialog should be set up in onPreExecute() and dismissed in onPostExecute())